# All curves of constant width yield good manhole covers?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Quoting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width):

*Curves of constant width are also the general answer to a brain teaser: "What shape can you make a manhole cover so that it cannot fall down through the hole?"*

Really?

**Don't there exist covers with constant width which cán be moved through their holes?**

Let me for that sake revisit the proof that a cover (or lid) in the shape of a Reuleaux triangle can not be moved through its hole:

Let us denote the interior of the triangle by the open $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. The lid (or cover) is considered as an embedded version of $\overline{U}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (informally speaking).$^\dagger$ Its width is $L>0$.

Let us show that -using continuous-in-time translation and rotations- if the lid is to pass from $\mathbb{R}^2\times (0,+\infty)$ initially to $\mathbb{R}^2\times (-\infty,0)$ in the end, then at some intermediate time $t_0$ the lid intersects $(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus U)\times \{0\}$. Let us list chronologically which of the lid's vertices comes first, second and third through the "horizontal plane" $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{0\}$ (if any simultaneities occur, one is free to choose this order). Let us look at the configuration of the lid precisely (say at time $t_0$) when the second vertex is coming through the horizontal plane. The intersection of the lid with that plane is -at that very moment $t_0$- a straight line-segment $[a,b]$ with length $|a-b|=L$. This line-segment then necessarily intersects with $(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus U)\times \{0\}$, i.e. the complement of the hole in the horizontal plane.

A similar proof works for any cover of constant width generated by a regular $2n+1$-gon. For a general curve $C$ of constant width $L$ it is however not clear that there exists a set of points $(x_j)_{1\leq j \leq 2n+1}$ on the curve $C$ so that for all $1\leq j\leq 2n+1$ the curve-segment $[x_{j+n},x_{j+n+1}]\subset C$ is at constant distance $L$ from $x_j$. In that case, a totally different proof is required to show that such a lid can not move through its hole. I do not know that proof and see no references to it e.g. on the aforementioned wikipedia-page nor elsewhere.

$^\dagger$ More precisely, the lid is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ of the form $f(\overline{U}\times \{0\})$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a Euclidean isometry.

Comment: "Don't there exist covers with constant width which cán be moved through their holes?"  Of course, not.  To move through a whole there most be some width measurement of the cover than is smaller than a width measure of the hole.  But it's constant width the widths are constant.

Comment: "This line-segment then necessarily intersects with the boundary of the hole, thus arriving at the sought-for contradiction. "  That's not a contradiction.  That's a confirmation.  To pass through the hole it must *NOT* ever intersect the boundary.  That is impossible.  So it can *NOT* pass through its hole.

Comment: @fleablood About your first comment: the thing is that what matters for the lid moving through the hole is the 'local' width, while the width in the definition of curve with constant width is defined globally, e.g. the length of the shadow when you shine a light from some angle.

Comment: @fleablood About your second comment: I was proceeding by first assuming that we can move the lid through the hole by some isometric homotopy (without intersecting the horizontal plane save for where the hole is) and then proceeding to derive a contradiction. Admittedly, I could have written the argument without resorting to proof by contradiction

Comment: Oh, so that was a proof that the R. triangle could *not* go through the hole? "the thing is that what matters for the lid moving through the hole is the 'local' width"  Yes, but isn't it basic to a constant width that to pass through you must go through all local widths and a width of the global maximum must be reached.  Isn't that the *definition*?  Any shape can *start* to go through the hole and any shape can finish going through the whole once it passes its widest local width.  But isn't the definition of "constant width" is the widest local width of any orietation is a constant value.

Comment: I suppose it is implied a flange of small extra constant width around the triangle or diangle rubbing on the flat portion preventing its fall-through.

Comment: @fleablood: I suppose that's a good start for a proof-attempt, but it is not clear a priori that I will not be able to find a smart succession of rotations and translations in such a way that these maxima in the local width are just never encountered at the height of the hole.

Comment: I will admit my vocabulary for terms like "constant width" and "passing through" is lacking and I wouldn't immediately know how to formally state *anything*.  But it seems to me that the heart of your objection is " it is however not clear that there exists a set of points (xj)1≤j≤2n+1 on the curve C so that for all 1≤j≤2n+1 the curve-segment [xj+n,xj+n+1]⊂C is at constant distance L from xj."  I imagine that the probably *IS* very clear from the definition of "constant width".  I think.

Comment: "I suppose it is implied a flange of small extra constant width around the triangle or diangle rubbing on the flat portion preventing its fall-through." That's always bothered me about the problem.  But I'm willing to accept that to "pass through" the hole must be wider than the cover.  Equal width can not allow passage.  Exactly why?.... well, friction, electronic bonding, flange... take your pick.  In abstract *strict* inequality is an acceptable condition.

Comment: The lid is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ while the hole is an open subset of the plane embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I think that adequately models a small flange.

Answer (score 0):

I may even be totally wrong. But what I imagined roughly is:

[image: constWidth]

an extended flange/shoulder in all positions 1) prevents the inside lobe/plug fall-through. If the outer contour is adequately broadened (the above plan has not adequate width around the manhole) it would, 2) cover the entire square always.